# How do I attach a video larger than 16 MB in Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video

It is not uncommon to see videos larger than 100 MB on whatsapp sent as a video clip. How is that accomplished?

I tried to find it on the internet. I know there are some obvious ways like the following, but none of them are convenient to send to view the video without much hassle. I want to know how to send it as a video message, as in the attached images. These videos are mostly longer than 20 minutes.

1. Send it as an attached document
2. Upload to a drive and send a link.
3. Ask the person their email address on Whatsapp and send them an email
4. Use Whatsapp to ask the person to meet physically and hand them the video in a USB flash drive.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling they are using a modded WhatsApp, though I don't know which since I've never tried it.

Comment: With root you can increase the media size limit in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs/ab-props.xml`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks very much. What's the shortest way to do that, making as little changes to my phone as possible